# Are these SQL indexes both necessary, or redundant: Over A only, and over A+B?

Tags: sql, database-performance, database-indexes

I want to create SQL indexes to speed up, for example, the search for "values of series" in the database. Each `Value` belongs to a `Series`, and has a date:

```
@Entity
class Series { … }

Value {
   Series series;
   Date date;
   …
   }
```

There are hundreds of series, each one with many thousands of values.

I often perform two types of searches:

1) Search all values that belong to a certain series (no matter their dates).

2) Search all values that belong to a certain series and that are within some specific date interval.

I may create two SQL indexes, one over the `series` column only, and the other over both `series` and `date` columns. Using Hibernate this would be:

```
@Table (indexes = {
        @Index (name = "idx1", columnList = "series"),
        @Index (name = "idx2", columnList = "series, date")
        })
```

My question is: Are the searches faster if I create both these indexes, or is it the same if I create only a single index like this:

```
@Table (indexes = {
        @Index (name = "idx", columnList = "series, date")
        })
```

Comment: Which version of SQL are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two indexes are redundant, because the second contains the same keys as the first one, in the same order (plus an additional key).

In general, this is a bad idea, because it is unnecessary redundancy (sort of a pun there ;)  So, just have the index with the two keys.

There are some edge cases where two such indexes might be useful.  For instance, if you have lots of data or equivalents are in a severely memory constrained environment, then the first index might fit in memory and the second one might not.  However, that would be a very rare situation.  And the better solution is to upgrade the hardware.

Answer (score 1):

You only need the one index with both columns.